# Kohana. Ошибки после установки.

Tags: php, kohana

Установил Kohana 3.3, в индексе проверил, всё ли подходит. Удалил install.php.
Теперь при обращении к контроллеру и его методу отображается ошибка.

"ErrorException [ 8 ]: Array to string conversion ~ SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Log\Writer.php [ 81 ]"

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой баг. Но есть и решение: Using [`array_filter()` w/`is_scalar()` to fix #4712](https://github.com/dm/core/commit/82b470b2827470da37b0e6771b77c369c3d2e5fb)

Сводится оно к фильтрации переменной `$message` вот таким образом:

```
array_filter($message, 'is_scalar')
```

Файл:

```
./system/classes/Kohana/Log/Writer.php:81
./system/classes/Kohana/Log/Writer.php:89
```

Comment: *..ого, я умудрился два раза ответ опубликовать*

Comment: Это нужно добавлять в файл Writer.php?
Если да, то в какие места?

Comment: в указанных строках вместо ``$message`` написать ``array_filter($message, 'is_scalar')``  
можете открыть ссылку и посмотреть diff

Comment: Старая ошибка исчезла.
Но появилась новая.
Теперь появляется такая:

"Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: A valid cookie salt is required. Please set Cookie::$salt."

Comment: ну так это и есть ваша ошибка, которую вы не видели - она не новая  
укажите Cookie::$salt и будет вам счастье

Comment: Я не умею. :С
Только вчера взялся за изучение Коханы.

Comment: сделайте поиск по Cookie::$salt и найдете ответ буквально по первой же ссылке  
вы не сможете изучить этот фреймворк без использования гугла и просмотра исходников

Comment: Окей.
Спасибо.